# Azure SendGrid doesn't send any email and raises no error

Tags: email, azure, sendgrid

I just created my SendGrid account an hour ago. I then created a C# Console app on my PC using **the sample code from Microsoft**. It runs fine, without any error message, but sends no email and leaves no trace in the system. What shall I do?

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using SendGrid;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace SendGridTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
            myMessage.From = new MailAddress("noreply@teacherspet.net.au");

            List<String> recipients = new List<String>
            {
                @"my1@gmail.com",
                @"my2@gmail.com",
                @"my3@gmail.com"
            };

            myMessage.AddTo(recipients);
            myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library";
            myMessage.Html = "<p>Hello World!</p>";


            var credentials = new NetworkCredential("azure_6e0d0...@azure.com", "mypassword");
            var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
            transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling an async method without an `await`.  Try `transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();`

Comment: Many thanks Brendan! After I did what you suggested it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As Brendan Green suggested, once changed the last line to

```
transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage).Wait();
```

it worked. Thanks Brendan!